# Satellite Internet Access: Can Use it to provide city wide wifi hotspot?

Tags: internet

Good day Network Engineers,
I would like to ask if I could have internet access using the satellite and provide it as a city wide wifi hotspot in our town. thank you!

Comment: Satellite and Wi-Fi are two completely separate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet links through geostationary satellites suffer from very high latency - something like 500 to 600 ms RTT as minimum - each bit needs to travel some 36,000 km twice per direction. Less generous provisioning can easily increase latency to 1500(!) ms and more.

It's OK for background data transmission, but a pain for interactive use and completely unusable for real-time applications like VoIP.